# How to keep metadata when using Get-PnPFile?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, properties

Is there a way to keep the metadata from the files downloaded with Get-PnPfile?

```
If(!(test-path $path))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
Get-PnPFile -Url $itemServerRelativeUrl -AsFile -Path $path -FileName $($fileName) -Force
```

I am able to download the files from multiple subwebs of the base site but have lost the Created By/Date and other metadata properties in the downloaded files.

Otherwise, is there a way to modify the downloaded file's extended properties to change them back to the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get file meta data using ***Get-PnPFile -AsListItem***

Refer the below syntax

```
Get-PnPFile [-Url] <String> -AsListItem [-ThrowExceptionIfFileNotFound] 
 [-Connection <PnPConnection>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

- Sample cmdlet

```
Get-PnPFile -Url /sites/project/_catalogs/themes/15/company.spcolor -AsListItem
```

- Your final scripts will look like below.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://{Tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{SiteName}"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive

$itemServerRelativeUrl="/sites/POC/Shared Documents1/General/Adatum 6.pdf"
$fileName="Voucherless exam steps.pdf"
$path="D:\POC\PNP"


If(!(test-path $path))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
Get-PnPFile -Url $itemServerRelativeUrl -AsFile  -Path $path -FileName $fileName -Force

$listItem=Get-PnPFile -Url $itemServerRelativeUrl -AsListItem

(Get-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents1" -Id $listItem.Id -Fields "Title","GUID","Created","Modified").FieldValues
```

- OutPut

[image: OutPut 1]

[image: OutPut 2]

- Refernece
- [Get file properties](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPFile.html#example-5)